# How to return a numpy array or list in a custom function using the eval dataframe method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, eval

I am using python 3.X. I am trying to use the [`eval()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html#pandas.eval)dataframe method including custom functions like this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'T': [0, 10, 0, 10, 10, 30],
    'P': [0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 0],
    'S': [25, 25, 25, 25, 40, 40]
})

def custom(A, B, C):
    # some operations

    aux = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': [0, 10, 0, 10, 10, 30],
    })
    return aux.A      # here is where I want to return the numpy array or list, or dataframe column

eq = 'RES = T + @custom(S, T, P) + 2'
df.eval(eq, engine='numexpr', inplace=True)
```

But I can only return one float or integer value in the function, a simple value.

So I would like to return a numpy array or a list of values because I want to use the result to operate with the rest of the equation variables. I get this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Another example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seawater as sw
from seawater.library import T90conv

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'T': T90conv([0, 10, 0, 10, 10, 30]),
    'P': [0, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, 0],
    'S': [25, 25, 25, 25, 40, 40]
})

cndr = sw.cndr                  # it returns a numpy array
eq = 'NEW = @cndr(S, T, P)'
df.eval(eq, engine='numexpr', inplace=True)
```

Is that possible? What kind of types can I return? Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: what is your expected/desired data set?

Comment: Can't you do this without eval?

Comment: I would like to operate with the returned value of the function as it were another column. I have added another example @maxu

Comment: I want to make it with eval because the user is who is going to write it (for instance the excel functions work like that). If not I would do it in a different way @coldspeed

Comment: @ChesuCR, `sw.cndr(df.S, df.T, df.P)` gives me `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,6) (18,)`

Comment: Yes, you should use them like this `sw.cndr(df['T'], df['P'], df['S'])` instead of using the dot notation @maxu

Comment: @ChesuCR, sorry, that was dumb - i didn't notice `df.T`

Comment: @ChesuCR, i couldn't make it work using `numexpr`. Using `engine='python'` - it works properly...

Comment: Oh!! Nice!! It won't be so fast but it's good enought for me, thank you. Write it into an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't make it work using `numexpr` engine - it always gives me `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`.

I also tried to convert that `numpy.ndarray` into `list` or `tuple` - it still says: `TypeError: unsupported expression type: <class 'tuple'>` or `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

But it does work with `python` engine:

```
In [47]: df.eval("NEW = @sw.cndr(S, T, P)", engine='python', inplace=True)

In [48]: df
Out[48]:
      P   S          T       NEW
0     0  25   0.000000  0.498008
1     0  25   9.997601  0.654990
2  1000  25   0.000000  0.506244
3  1000  25   9.997601  0.662975
4     0  40   9.997601  1.000073
5     0  40  29.992802  1.529967
```

What about the following workaround?

```
In [77]: df = df.assign(RES=sw.cndr(df['S'], df['T'], df['P'])) \
                .eval("RES = T + RES + 2", inplace=False)

In [78]: df
Out[78]:
      P   S          T        RES
0     0  25   0.000000   2.498008
1     0  25   9.997601  12.652591
2  1000  25   0.000000   2.506244
3  1000  25   9.997601  12.660576
4     0  40   9.997601  12.997674
5     0  40  29.992802  33.522769
```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround but I need to do it directly within the expression. I appreciate your help

Comment: The next step will be let me choose what function can be used in the expression, because it could be a security hole if the user can execute any function